# Values becoming nan for machine learning model

Tags: python

I am getting zero accuracy and nan for loss using cross entropy after first few terms. I have input X to predict y.
Here is my class:

```
class Multiclass(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.hidden = nn.Linear(20, 70)
        self.act = nn.ReLU()
        self.output = nn.Linear(70, 13)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.act(self.hidden(x))
        x = self.output(x)
        return x
```

I have tried normalizing, changing y to one hot vectors, decrease learning rate, and have played around with model size.